# how to call wait until function is executed in node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

I Have written a function which deletes the data in mongodb using mongoose and kept in separate folder DB.js, the code looks like

```
delete_user : function(data) {
    connection.findOne({email:data}, function(err, result) {
        connection.findById(result.id, function(err, val) { 
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            connection .findByIdAndRemove(val.id, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
            });
        });
    });
},
```

Connection that are needed to make connection mongodb are written in other file

In test file (written in mocha framework),I required the file and made a call to this function as

```
after('Flust out the created user', function(done) {
    Db.delete_user(req_body.email);
    console.log("User "+req_body.email+" deleted");
    done();
})
```

Same code is used two different test files say a.test.js and b.test.js

when i run the test file using mocha

it throws error as

```
Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

user that was created from the file a.test.js is deleted in the db
user created from the file b.test.js is not deleted and the error is thrown

Comment: I cannot tell what you are asking.  If you want to know when `delete_user()` is done, you need to pass a callback into it that will be called when it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add callback in your function :

```
delete_user : function(data, callback) {
connection.findOne({email:data}, function(err, result) {
    connection.findById(result.id, function(err, val) { 
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        connection .findByIdAndRemove(val.id, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                return callback();
        });
    });
});
},
```

And then :

```
after('Flust out the created user', function(done) {
    Db.delete_user(req_body.email, function(){
        console.log("User "+req_body.email+" deleted");
        done();
    });
 })
```